# Which build action to chose to execute Groovy scripts on jenkins slave JVM

Tags: groovy, jenkins

I am able to execute Groovy scripts on slave JVM using the slave's groovy console offered by Jenkins.
(e.g) 
println System.getenv("PATH")

prints the value of path variable of the slave node

when I made the same call in my Jenkins job which is executed on slave, using build action execute system groovy script 
It creates the workspace on slave but groovy script is executed in server JVM
(e.g) 
println System.getenv("PATH")

prints the value of path variable at the Master's Node

Is there any way of executing my groovy scripts on client JVM in Jenkins job without installing groovy on slave node?

Comment: Jenkins installs groovy on slaves when it executes the first job. You never need to install it.. So why worry about run groovy code without groovy on slave?

Comment: I assume your problem is that the Groovy script supplied as a build steps runs on the master instead of the executing slave; is that right?

Answer (score 0):

On the main Jenkins screen click on the slave you want to run the script on and add `script` to the end of the url. This should load the script console for that slave.

If my base Jenkins url is `jenkinsurl` then on my setup the script console for my windows slave is `jenkinsurl/computer/Windows/script`.